# ActiveRecord has_many association NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

```
class DistributionResults < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eqadistribution
  belongs_to :meter
  belongs_to :user
```

And

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prime_contractor
  has_many :distribution_results
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :meters
  has_many :device_capabilities, :through => :meters
  has_many :email_addresses
```

All associations and associated functions appear to work as expected except for the user -> distribution_results has_many / belongs_to

On trying to create a user.distribution_result I get the error:

NameError:
       uninitialized constant User::DistributionResult

I have a user_id field in the distribution_results table.

Full trace of error is:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::DistributionResult
from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:158:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:271:in `compute_class'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:267:in `klass'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:118:in `klass'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:39:in `reader'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `distribution_results'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/railties/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/railties/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/craigwebster/bolton-eqa-website/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

And I'm trying to implement a before destroy call back method in the User Model

```
before_destroy :check_any_email_addresses, :check_any_meters, :check_any_distribution_results, :check_any_addresses

def check_any_email_addresses   
if email_addresses.any?     
  self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete Prime Contractor while an associated email exists."
  return false   
end 
end 

def check_any_meters   
  if meters.any?     
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete Prime Contractor while an associated meter exists."
    return false   
  end 
end 

def check_any_distribution_results   
  if distribution_results.any?     
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete Prime Contractor while an associated distribution result exists."
    return false   
  end 
end 

def check_any_addresses   
  if addresses.any?     
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete Prime Contractor while an associated address exists."
    return false   
  end 
end
```

All the other callback methods work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update:

It just occurred to me that your model is plural. It should be `DistributionResult` which has the table `distribution_results`.

Change your call to:

```
user.distribution_results
```

Note the pluralization of result. This is because a `user` `has_many` `distribution_results`

Comment: If I try this test @user=User.new
 => #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$XpQeQU78OyQZ2j18sg6.4eYWMSwoNh4Z.x7jML82c95...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: etc @user.distribution_results
NameError: uninitialized constant User::DistributionResult

Comment: The error will reference a particular line in a particular file. Can you please append that to your question?

Comment: The stack trace at this point is: from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:158:in `compute_type'
 from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:271:in `compute_class'
 from /Users/craigwebster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-e43545794963/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:267:in `klass' plus more

Comment: I want to use a before_delete callback of the following:            def check_any_distribution_results   
    if distribution_results.any?     
      self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete Prime Contractor while an associated distribution result exists."
      return false   
    end 
  end

Comment: I'm pretty sure the association is fine. Something else is wrong. If you want to amend the question I can take a look.